# How to get page width and height via pdfContentByte

Tags: c#, itext

I meet a problem about how to get the width and height of the
pdf file. The code snippet is as following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(fileOutPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream("some_image.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
            var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1); //stamper.GetOverContent(pageNum)
            Image image = Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
            pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
            stamper.Close();
    }
}
```

I try to create a watermark on the pdf I want, but what I need is 
how to get the correct width and height of the original pdf to 
make me could set the image in the correct position.
Is that possible to make that via pdfContentByte, or there is some 
other way to do that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible to make that via pdfContentByte

No. A `PdfContenByte` instance represents a very large canvas only a section of which is eventually displayed as page (or form XObject or annotation or...).

You can retrieve the location and size of that section using the `PdfReader` method `GetCropBox` providing the page number in question as argument.